# How do I allow regular users to access specific folder only accessible to admin?

Tags: shared-folders

I have one admin users. The rest are regular users

I want regular users to be able to access

```
H:\business\shared\Insync\biz\somestuff
```

But only that folder and anything below.

Not H: in general. Not H:\business

Just that one small folder.

How do I do so?

Operating system is windows 10

Comment: *Basics:*  
Create a group,   
make the group have access rights to the folder and subfolders,  
make the relevant users be members of that group.

Comment: You'll need to clarify what operating system and version you're asking for advice on.

Answer (score 0):

I go to administrator account. I go to the folder. I right click. I click share. I choose the username of regular user that I want to do this with.

The result is pretty awesome.

If I want to access different folder I have to input administrator password.

I can however, access that folder.